# drag and drop when i drop the textview in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener

what is my code do here is just  drag the textview from the pink area and drop it to the yellow area

the problem is when i drag the textView in  the bottom of the screen
textview will be invisible

Please if you didn't get my question ask me in a comment

I tried to search a lot but not getting any pointers

here is the screenshot and the code

[image]

**this is the main activity class**

```
package com.javapapers.android.drag_drop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import com.javapapers.android.drag_drop.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,OnDragListener{
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.textView1).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.pinkLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.yellowLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
              view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
              view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

    }  
    public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
          int action = dragevent.getAction();
          switch (action) {
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
              Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
              Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into "+layoutview.toString());
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
              Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from "+layoutview.toString());
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");
            View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
            container.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                  Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
              break;
          default:
            break;
          }
          return true;
    }
}
```

and this is the activity_main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pinkLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:background="#FF8989"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dragtext"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/yellowLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pinkLayout"
        android:background="#FFCC00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1):

This is because is not hitting the dropped case but rather the exited and ended cases, so the visibility of the view is never set to visible again